# Search and Call object associated with string in a hashmap in java

Tags: java, object, hashmap, user-input

So i'm trying to make a text game in java for a project and i have a problem in the main loop.I have the available commands in a hashmap named commands in the class CommandWords and i want to check if the user input exists in the hashmap and if it does to execute the associated object.But i can't exactly find a way.Here is my code.I understand it's probably an if but i don't know how to check.

```
     public void play()
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to the world of JZork " +player.name);
printWelcome();
boolean finished = false;
while (! finished) {
Command command = parser.getCommand();
  if(command == null) {
        System.out.println("I don't understand...");
    }
}
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it the way you said, but you would need to learn to use Java reflection. This isn't THAT hard, but you aren't going to like it.

```
if (command.equals("quit")) {
    quit();
}
else if (command.equals("whatever")) {
    whatever();
}
```

This isn't that elegant, but it's easy to implement.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind as a back up plan in case i don't find something more elegant.Can you refer me to a good post so i can figure out how to use Java reflection?

Comment: Go to the javadocs for Class and then look at the getMethods() call. There are also calls that are more specific. You'll get an array of Method objects, and Method has getName() and getParameterTypes() to help you figure out the method you really want. But I've never seen anyone who would program something this way. You want to parse user input and handle it yourself, not let the user in effect make your method calls for you. Just my opinin.